# Does an infinite set of points form a line segment?

Tags: geometry

Say we have two points in a 2 dimensional space:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
```

If we generate infinite points of the form (0, x) where x is a function that generates infinite, uniformly distributed values 0 to 1, do we get a line segment between the two endpoints?

Or is it an undefined problem of the form `inf * 0`?

Comment: from the way you describe, you would only get a countable subset of the line connecting the two points. But the line itself is an uncountable set, so what you've generated cannot be the whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question isn't really precise. There are two ways to interpret it:

- **You put down *every* point between $(0, 0)$ and $(0,1)$.** In this case, you're just describing (as in Semiclassical's answer) the line segment between the two points, and this construction in general is called the *convex hull*.
- **You put down infinitely many points between $(0, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$.** In this case, what you get depends on *exactly what* points you put down. For instance, if you only put down the points $(0, x)$ where $x$ is *rational* - there are infinitely many of these! - then you *don't* get the whole line segment (e.g. you're missing $\pi\over 4$).

In particular, it's a surprising fact - and the beginning of *set theory* - that as long as you put down *countably many* points (that is, a point $x_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$), you'll still miss lots of points on the line. That is, the set of real numbers between $0$ and $1$ is **uncountable**. This can be proved by [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument). So in order to get the whole line segment, you'll need to put down uncountably many points.

But it's not even an issue of how many points you put down, but also *where* you put them. Think about the function $f(x)=2x$; this function takes $[0, {1\over 2}]$ to $[0, 1]$, so there are [the same number of points in each interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo's_paradox). So you could put down as many points as the whole line segment has, and still miss lots of it.

---

Tl;dr: **Infinite sets are weird, and you have to be careful when asking questions about them to make your ideas precise.**

Comment: My question stated infinitely, not every, but this is useful. I understand that distinction. I'm generally curious if, in theory, higher dimensional objects can truly arise from lower dimensional ones, to which your answer implies yes (in the `every` case). In this case my question is about going from 0 dimensions to 1. Is it correct to say that in our example a 1 dimensional line arose from 0 dimensional points?

Comment: @maxhud Yes, the line is a union of (infinitely many) points. Indeed, *every* set is a union of one-element subsets - $X=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$ - so this is a very general fact. Incidentally, if you find this weird, you're not alone: a number of mathematicians, and philosophers of mathematics, have argued that there are meaningful mathematical constructions which are *not* the union of points, and distinguished between the number line (which is a union of points) and intuitively-given continua (space, time) which aren't. (cont'd).

Comment: I believe this was advanced by Weyl in his book *Das Kontinuum*, and others at around the same time (Brouwer?); incidentally, the idea reappears in the context of **topos theory**. But classically, lines are made of points.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If you don't mind, I'm curious what your basis for saying "intuitively-given continua (space, time) which aren't [the union of points]" is.   In other words, I'm curious what might lead you to be confident there is a distinction between theory and reality with respect to continuity of points (of any dimension).

Comment: @maxhud Oh, I'm not confident of it - in fact, I wildly disagree with that point of view. But it is a point of view that some people (much smarter than me) hold, so I wanted to point it out for fairness. If you want details, you should probably read (a translation of) Das Kontinuum; I actually don't know it super well, so I can't really help.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay thank you for all the help!